# How do I generate a proc to return successive entries in a hash, transformed?

Tags: ruby

I would like to generate a proc that, when called, returns successive values for any Enumerable. In other words:

```
a_proc = generate_proc([:a, :b, :c])
a_proc.call # => :a
a_proc.call # => :b
```

etc.

Ideally, I'd want to translate it before returning, too, so it might get used like:

```
a_proc = generate_proc([:a, :b, :c ]) { |e| "Element: #{e.inspect}" }
a_proc.call # => "Element: :a"
a_proc.call # => "Element: :b"
a_proc.call # => "Element: :c"
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a `proc`? Is a class, method or a lambda an option too?

Comment: The calling API (which I don't control) requires it, alas.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but I think it may meet your needs:

```
an_enum = [:a, :b, :c].each

an_enum.next # => :a
an_enum.next # => :b
```

And:

```
an_enum = [:a, :b, :c].map { |e| "Element: #{e.inspect}" }.each
# or, if you want to defer calling the block...
an_enum = [:a, :b, :c].lazy.map { |e| "Element: #{e.inspect}" }

an_enum.next # => "Element: :a"
an_enum.next # => "Element: :b"
an_enum.next # => "Element: :c"
```

For more information, check out [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html) and [Enumerator::Lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html).

**UPDATE FROM FUTURE, SMARTER, HANDSOMER ME:**

To answer your original question, you can turn any object's method into a bound, callable object with `Object#method`. We can even do it to `Enumerator#next`!

```
an_enum = [:a, :b, :c].each
a_proc = an_enum.method(:next)

a_proc.call # => :a
a_proc.call # => :b
a_proc.call # => :c
```

Comment: That is handy, thanks. Unfortunately, I need somethign that responds to #call, but that

Comment: will come in handy later.

Comment: @EricSchwartz This is maybe a bit too sneaky, but just for fun: `def an_enum.call; self.next end`

Comment: Or sneakier: `an_enum.singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :call, :next)`

Comment: Oh, this is better: `a_proc = an_enum.method(:next)`

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
def generate_proc x, &postproc
  myobj = Fiber.new { x.each { |v| Fiber.yield v }}

  postproc ? -> () { postproc.call myobj.resume } :
             -> () {               myobj.resume }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is exactly what you're asking for:

```
def generate_proc(list, &transform)
  enum = list.to_enum
  if transform
    proc { transform[enum.next] }
  else
    proc { enum.next }
  end
end
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to return one of two different procs, depending on whether or not there's a transform, rather than performing the check inside the proc.

Comment: You can also return a handle to the existing `Enumerator#send` method (instead of wrapping it in another Proc) with `enum.method(:next)` instead of `proc { enum.next }`. :-)